# expanding the dataframe by resampling each row to have a range before and after each specific row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that we have this dataframe:

```
date                   value    
2018-01-10 9:30:00       0      
2018-02-11 10:00:00      1
```

I want to expand each row to become in range of 2 hours before and after that time and being resampled in each 30 minutes and the value should be copied for the newly generated rows.

Here is the results that I want to have:

```
date                   value    
2018-01-10 7:30:00      0
2018-01-10 8:00:00      0
2018-01-10 8:30:00      0 
2018-01-10 9:00:00      0
2018-01-10 9:30:00      0  
2018-01-10 10:00:00     0 
2018-01-10 10:30:00     0
2018-01-10 11:00:00     0 
2018-01-10 11:30:00     0

2018-02-11 8:00:00      1
2018-02-11 8:30:00      1
2018-02-11 9:00:00      1
2018-02-11 9:30:00      1
2018-02-11 10:00:00     1
2018-02-11 10:30:00     1
2018-02-11 11:00:00     1 
2018-02-11 11:30:00     1
2018-02-11 12:00:00     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question, see below code (**which is wrong**),

```
(pd.concat([df, df.rename(lambda x:x+pd.DateOffset(hours=2)),
            df.rename(lambda x:x+pd.DateOffset(hours=-2))])
   .sort_index()
   .resample('30min')
   .ffill())
```

New answer (assuming data is pandas series),

```
def func(s):
    df = (pd.concat([s, s.rename(lambda x:x+pd.DateOffset(hours=2)),
                        s.rename(lambda x:x+pd.DateOffset(hours=-2))])
            .sort_index()
            .resample('30min')
            .ffill())
    return df

pd.concat(func(data.iloc[[i]]) for i in range(data.shape[0]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. Will revisit later